# How to replace text between quotation marks with something from another file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, replace

I have the following kind of text:

```
$OU = 'or';
$DINHEIRO_CAIXA = 'Cash balance';
$PAGINA = 'Page';
$DE = 'from';
$ENVIAR = 'Send';
$PRINCIPAL = 'Main';
```

I've already got all the text within the single quotation marks using

`cat arquivo | grep -oP "'[^']+'" | tr -d "'"`

This extracted text was then translated to Portuguese, but now I don't know how to replace the original text between single quotation marks with the translated text, I was looking for something like

```
$OU = 'ou';
$DINHEIRO_CAIXA = 'Dinheiro em caixa';
$PAGINA = 'Pagina';
$DE = 'de';
$ENVIAR = 'enviar';
$PRINCIPAL = 'Principal';
```

I've tried using `grep -F` to replace the file itself, but it failed miserably because the pattern didn't match since I don't have the quotation marks on the new file, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F\' '
    { getline translate_text <"trans_file";
      print $1, translate_text, $3;
    }' OFS=\' original_file
```

`original_file` is your original file; `trans_file` is your translated of original_file as in below format:

```
ou
Dinheiro em caixa
Pagina
de
enviar
Principal
```

Comment: This adds a new line before the closing quotation mark when generating a new file, is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: I think you would need to do `dos2unix trans_file` for that (if you generated that file in Windows and now you are working on Linux)

Comment: That worked out just fine, thanks!